# Is there a way to get size of a procedure?

Tags: delphi, hook

I'm using the following routine to patch functions in the RTL.

```
procedure PatchCode(const AddrProc: Pointer; const CodeSize: NativeUInt;
  const Code: Pointer);
var
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  VirtualProtect(AddrProc, CodeSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect);
  Move(Code^, AddrProc^, CodeSize);
  VirtualProtect(AddrProc, CodeSize, OldProtect, OldProtect);
end;
```

However when I tweak my patch-methods their size changes causing code like this to break:

```
//PatchRedirect calls PatchCode internally  
PatchRedirect(AddrGetMem,{codesize = }17, @RedirectGetMem, JUMPS_GETMEM);
```

Is there a way to determine the size of a method at compile-time or runtime? (either one is fine).

<sub>I'm hoping for a general solution, but
if it only works for asm routines that's fine for my purposes.</sub>

**Use case**
One use case for this is a faster version of FillChar.
99% of the time `FillChar` is used as a `ZeroMem`. 
So I patch `System.ZeroMem` with:

```
xor r8,r8
jmp FastFillChar;
```

and I patch `System.FillChar` with

```
movzx R8,R8b
mov r9,$0101010101010101
imul r8,r9
jmp FastFillChar
```

That way I can make the FillChar a tiny bit faster for those 99% of cases.
*Or it would if anyone bothered to actually use zeromem*

**Update**
Thanks to Rudy I think I have a solution applicable to a limited subset.

Comment: I'm not looking for this trick: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=99601  That will never work, because `ret` can be anywhere in a routine, not necessarily at the end.

Comment: I've seen somewhere that something like this was used: `procedure xAfter; begin end;` with the proper compiler hints so the linker won't eliminate it. And then calculating the difference between the two (run-time) addresses... Could that work in your case?

Comment: It would, but can I be sure that Delphi will not reorder routines? And what is the magical hint that will not eliminate dead code (without it being globally applicable). Also there is the problem of code alignment inserting extra nops between the end of the previous routine and the start of the next.

Comment: Usually a patch does not path all the code, it merely puts a jump to the improved code (and saves the old code). To patch, you must know the size of the code you patched, and sometimes even the size of the instrcutions you replace.

Comment: These nops should not cause any problems, right?

Comment: No and perhaps I can do this: `length:= (@routine2 - @routine1) - number of $90 bytes between 1 and 2`. But I'm not sure Delphi always sticks to simple nops as spacers.

Comment: Why does it matter? nops are code too. It doesn't matter if code is part of the routine or just nops. You can still patch.

Comment: It does if the nops are part of the source, because that might make the source too large to fit inside the destination, causing a crash.

Comment: Delphi does not only use $90 as nops, it will also insert other code like $8BC0 `mov eax,eax` as a nop. So detecting nops is non-trivial.

Comment: I don't quite understand "too large to fit in the destination"? Are you patching the entire code? If so, why? And how do you know your patch is not larger than the original anyway?

Comment: I create a dummy routine containing the code to patch, see **use case** above.  I patch the entire code of this dummy routine, which often fits inside 16 bytes, but sometimes does not.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to get size of a procedure?

If you have access to the source code, yes.
Delphi puts the generated code of routines in the same order as it is declared in the `implementation` section.

As long as the destination code you are trying to patch and the source code you're getting your patches from are compiled with the same parameters of `{$CODEALIGN n}` there is no problem.

For Win32, the default value is 4 and the Win32 RTL is compiled with alignment 4. 
The code alignment for the Win64 RTL is `{$CodeAlign 16}`.

As long as the code alignment in your code and the patch recipient matches it the following code will work fine:

```
ProcSize:= NativeInt(@Routine2) - NativeInt(@Routine1);  
PatchCode(@Routine1, ProcSize, @System.Something);
```

Any alignment nops will only increase the size up to the next multiple of `$CodeAlign` and the destination code is aligned the same way so you should be fine.

Obviously Routine1 had better be really short, otherwise you'll run into trouble, perhaps it's a good idea to assert that @dest is not a naked jmp to some other routine before patching if `ProcSize > $CodeAlign`.

Answer (score 3):

I once wrote a piece of patching code myself, which doesn't overwrite the entire function at all, but just a jump to it at the start of the procedure. The size of the old procedure is of little importance because of that. Additionally, the class remembers the original content, so you can also 'unhook' the procedure by restoring that code.

It's written a long time ago, and I didn't have to use it in a long time, so I hope it still works in a more modern environment.

```
unit BigProcHook;

interface

uses
  Windows, sysUtils;

type
  PHack = ^THook;
  THook = packed record
    OpCodeCall : Byte;
    OFFTo      : Integer;
    OpCodeRet  : Byte;
  end;
  TBackup = THook;

  TBigProcHook = class
  private
    FOldProc, FNewProc: Pointer;
    FBackupped: Boolean;
    FHooked: Boolean;
    FOriginal: TBackup;
    procedure SetHooked(const Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure InstallHook(Hook: THook);
    procedure OverwriteProc;
  public
    constructor Create(AOldProc, ANewProc: Pointer; Install: Boolean = True);
    property Hooked: Boolean read FHooked write SetHooked;
  end;

implementation

{ TBigProcHook }

constructor TBigProcHook.Create(AOldProc, ANewProc: Pointer;
  Install: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create;

  FOldProc := AOldProc;
  FNewProc := ANewProc;

  if Install then
    SetHooked(True);
end;

procedure TBigProcHook.InstallHook(Hook: THook);
var
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  // Change protection of oldproc memory
  if VirtualProtect(FOldProc, SizeOf(THook), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  try
    if not FBackupped then
    begin
      Move(FOldProc^, FOriginal, SizeOf(THook));
      FBackupped := True;
    end;
    // Overwrite the old procedure
    Move(Hook, FOldProc^, SizeOf(THook));
  finally
    VirtualProtect(FOldProc, SizeOf(THook), OldProtect, OldProtect);
  end
  else
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;

procedure TBigProcHook.OverwriteProc;
// Overwrites the first few calls of OldProc with a call to NewProc and a Ret.
var
  Hook: THook;
begin
  // Create a tiny little redirection
  with Hook do begin
    OpCodeCall := $E8; // = CALL}
    OFFTo      := PAnsiChar(FNewProc) - PAnsiChar(FOldProc) - 5;
    OpCodeRet  := $C3; // = RET
  end;

  InstallHook(Hook);
end;

procedure TBigProcHook.SetHooked(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  // Toggle hook.
  if FHooked <> Value then
    if Value then
      OverwriteProc
    else
      InstallHook(FOriginal);

  FHooked := Value;
end;

initialization
end.
```

Which you can call like this: (in the example it's called in the initialization and finalization of a unit)

```
var
  FHook: TBigProcHook;
initialization
  FHook := TBigProcHook.Create(@ProcedureToReplace, @ReplacementProcedure);
finalization
  FHook.Hooked := False;
  FHook.Free;
```

Originally posted on the [Dutch forum NLDelphi.com](http://www.nldelphi.com/showthread.php?32977-IsAltGrPressed-of-Hooken-van-functies).

Comment: Thanks, I know about the jump/call patch, but I want to patch/overwrite the entire routine.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why?

Comment: I'm doing some optimization of BrainMM and the author of that particular library uses the complete overwrite trick, see: https://github.com/d-mozulyov/BrainMM/tree/development, also sometimes a simple jmp is not enough sometimes you need to do a tiny bit of initialization before the jmp so you can simplify the main routine or prevent duplication of code.